# Regularized Dynamo Secondary Keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, schema

I am working with a data set that has a secondary index with a sort key that ultimately has user entered information in it. For the sake of the question, consider it a "postal address" field.  This model is to permit quick queries of this data for a particular postal address.

Because it is user entered I am finding myself wanting to regularize it before using it as a key. For instance, by stripping spaces and making it a common case.   My thinking being that if someone made a trivial capitalization or spacing error it wouldn't be identified as a different address.

Is this a pattern that people typically do if they are creating a key on user entered data? Are "user entered keys" considered harmful? Any obvious pitfalls?

Comment: Regardless of our data back end it is generally always a good idea to sanitize user data. Yes this could, in the dynamo case, lead to false duplicates, but that could be the least of your worries, as there could be injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: What kind of injection vulnerabilities are you referring to @jeffrey ? DynamoDB doesn't suffer from injection attacks the same way traditional SQL databases do.

Comment: Not in the same way sure, but untreated user input going into a secondary key opens up the possibility a user could intentionally cause records to be overwritten or duplicated maliciously based on manipulation of that key value. Depending on what your primary keys are, this might not be a huge vulnerability, certainly not as bad as say a sql 'drop tables;' but I would still say, in principle untreated user input into any data base has the potential to allow end users to alter data outside of the programs interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure you get your normalization function right. Simply stripping spaces might not be a great idea. For example, `Hight Railroad` and `High Trail Road` might both normalize to `hightrailroad` which probably isn't what you want. Instead, you might want to replace one or more consecutive spaces with a single dash or something along those lines.

If you get the normalization right, you should be fine. Others have mentioned vulnerabilities related to overwriting data but you said that this is a Global Secondary Index. You can't write to a GSI so you don't need to worry about this. Also, the user entered data is the sort key. As long as you control the hash key, you will be fine.

One thing I would be cautious of is the data distribution. Any time there is a user-influenced key whether it be direct user input or a side effect of a user action such as a timestamp, you need to take care to avoid unbalanced data distributions which could lead to hot shards and/or throttling